# HTML form input equal to var = go to URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to create a html form where I want to be redirected to a url if the input you insert is the same as the value of a variable. I have tried to make it work in many different ways, but I have not succeeded. : - /

Someone who can help?

Here is my code:

My HTML-form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" onsubmit="script.js">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

My JS:

```
var country = 'Brazil';
var input = $("input[id='myInput']").val();

$("#submit").on("submit", function(event){
  if (country == input) {
     window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things. Since you are targeting the submit button and not the form, your event listener should be "click" not "submit." Next, call `event.preventDefault()` inside the click function. Finally, you want to get the input value *after* you click the button, so that assignment has to go inside your click function:

```js
var country = "Brazil";

$("#submit").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input = $("input#myInput").val();

  if (country == input) {
    console.log("redirect");
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  } else {
    console.log("don't redirect");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form autocomplete="off" onsubmit="script.js">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to init the value after the form is submitted otherwise it will be undefined.

```
var country = 'Brazil';

$("#submit").on("submit", function(event){
let input = $("input[id='myInput']").val();
  if (country == input) {
     window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e){
  e && e.preventDefault();
  var country = 'Brazil';
  var input = $('#myInput').val();
  if (country === input) {
     window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
});
```

You need to get the value of the input after the click (or submit) event is fired

Answer (score 0):

Place `input = $("input[id='myInput']").val();` as first line inside the function which handles the `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

So your code actually almost work. Minor adjustments:

```js
var country = 'Brazil';
$("#submit").on("click", function(event){ // this event change to click since we change the type=submit on the input
  var input = $("input[id='myInput']").val();  // this line moves inside the event  
  if (country == input) {
     window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
  else { alert('B R A Z I L type Brazil to redirect');}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form autocomplete="off" onsubmit="script.js">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="GO?" /> <!-- Changed from submit to button -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#submit').on('submit', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
        var country = 'Brazil';
        var input = $("input[id='myInput']").val();
        if (country == input) {
          window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head> 
<body>
<form autocomplete="off" id="submit">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```